# iOS13 and 14, WebView didFinish not work. it not call when comeback from second page after call goBack()

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview, ios13, ios14

iOS13 and 14, WebView didFinish not work. it not call when comeback from second page after call goBack()

Step

1. open webview
2. click some url and then redirect to second page
3. press back by call goBack() on navigation bar
4. webview redirect to first page <---- didFinish not call on iOS13, 14
   but on iOS12 can working fine.

Answer (score 0):

yes, read on swiftui and the new app lifecycle. hint: @main